# Does any EF extension exist which supports filtered partial updates?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

To update an entity I either need to query it and change its properties or attach as modified or change after attachment.

But what I actually need is something like:

```
context.MyEntities.UpdateWhere( 
    entity => { entity.IsDeleted = true; entity.DeletedDate = today},
    entity => entitiesToDelete.Contains(entity.id) && !entity.IsDeleted));
```

I expect similar (parameterized) SQL to be emitted:

```
update MyEntitiesTable
set IsDeleted = 1, DeletedDate = @today
where id in (...ids list...) and IsDeleted = 0;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EntityFramework.Extended has a batch update and delete feature. [GitHub](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended#batch-update-and-delete)

Example syntax for your question would be along the lines of:

```
context.MyEntities.Where(entity => entitiesToDelete.Contains(entity.id) && !entity.IsDeleted)
        .Update(t => new MyEntity { entity.IsDeleted = true, entity.DeletedDate = today });
```